# PDO - PHP query executed again without call

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry for my english.
I perform a unique query INSERT but in database are created many records equal.
I have a php cms mvc with pattern singleton and registry.
When I call a controller are loaded all models of core, including the model that manages the database.

I write a piece of code:

```
class DB extends global_core
{
    private $PDO;
    private $result;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function query($query)
    { 
        $this->result = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
        $this->result->execute();
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

In another model run this method:

```
class Stats extends global_core
{
    private $stored_agent = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->stored_agent) 
        $this->saveAgent();
    }

    public function saveAgent()
    {
        if ($this->stored_agent) return;

        $this->DB->query('INSERT ...');  

        echo 'ok';

        $this->stored_agent = true;
    }
}
```

Now in my database are created "n" equal record, but in video is printed rightly only "ok" and not "okokokokokokok".

why?

however, if i call the method from the current controller I get, rightly, only a new record.

```
class page extends controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->loadInfo();
    }

    protected function loadInfo()
    {
        $this->Stats->saveAgent();
    }
}
```

so it works properly...

where is the problem?

Comment: Make sure, that there is no other INSERT statement in your code. Modify the query to that it will fail. If the query fails output a debug stack trace. You will then see what function called your save agent function. Perhaps ther are multiple calls distributed around in your code. If you have XDebug profiling (ore any other profile) available you can find the callers in the profile as well.

Comment: thanks markus,
I inserted an error in the query and I printed the errorInfo of pdo. Stack trace shown me 9 classes that are called. But the method call is one.

Comment: Your application errors out on the first occurence. Is the stack trace the one you expected? You might want to implement a logging solution instead of the echo debugging. Perhaps you echo in an output buffer that is not displayed. It's hard to assist remotely, without knowing the inner workings of your app

Comment: it's all ok for me. It's possibile that the singleton create new instances of the core? `public static function singleton(){
        if(self::$_instance === null){
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
was a problem of misconfiguration url rewriting.
Recalling an image does not exist on the server, was charged an error page of the site that instantiate again the core ...

```
<img src="file not present" >
```